# how can I do 2d 3d multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two array one is 3d :

```
np.array([[[1,2,3],[3,2,1]],
          [[2,3,2],[1,2,5]]])
```

and one 2d array :

```
np.array([[2,3],
          [3,4]])
```

and I want to multiply these two to get

```
np.array([[[2,4,6],[9,6,3]],
          [[6,9,6],[4,8,20]]])
```

How can I do this using numpy package? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
In [129]: b[:,:,None] * a
Out[129]: 
array([[[ 2,  4,  6],
        [ 9,  6,  3]],

       [[ 6,  9,  6],
        [ 4,  8, 20]]])
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Guanxiong.Liu You can tell this to community as well by accepting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

With following names:

```
main = np.array([[[1,2,3],[3,2,1]],
                 [[2,3,2],[1,2,5]]])
fac = np.array([[2,3],
                [3,4]])
```

It can managed with iteration as follows:

```
a1 = []
for i in [0,1]:
    a2 = []
    for j in [0,1]:
            a2.append(main[i][j]*fac[i][j]) 
    a1.append(a2)

print(a1)
```

Output:

```
[[array([2, 4, 6]), array([9, 6, 3])], [array([6, 9, 6]), array([ 4,  8, 20])]]
```